# Errors LNK2019 and LNK 1120

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I keep getting the same error when I try to compile my program (http://pastebin.com/TABk4bya). The error says -

```
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

1>c:\users\logan\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Assignment 09\Debug\Assignment 09.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I have tried to search but I cannot seem to find out what the problem is.

P.S. I have pasted it to pastebin so you can easily see/point out which lines the error is on. Thank You!

Comment: Isn't `Main` suppose to be `main`? (IOW lowercase)

Comment: Omg, I have been so stumped for the last couple hours. I love how simple things like that can go completely unnoticed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
int Main()
```

it should be

```
int main()
```

Case matters! `Main` is not the same as `main`.